# How to visualize sent XML stream with a CXF generated client

Tags: java, soap, jakarta-ee, cxf

I would like to be able to see the XML Stream generated by my CXF generated from WSDL client.
Is there a way to do this ?

For example, I'm building my request with Java objects, and I would like to see the XML stream built by CXF before it sends it to the server.

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LoggingInterceptors CXF includes.

See:
http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) to capture the web service requests and responses *as* they're sent and received.

Comment: ok thank you, I started using also TcpTrace on Windows, also I'm now writing a servlet to analyse the request, I guess we can't analyse the Xml request from the WS client, I think it'a shame...

Comment: But TCPMon will intercept the client/server communication, so you'll see stuff as it comes from the client.